# How to make it read from a text file c#

Tags: c#

```
   class Program
    {
        static List<Book> newBook = new List<Book>();
        static List<BorrowDetails> borrowList = new List<BorrowDetails>();
        static Book book = new Book();
        static BorrowDetails borrow = new BorrowDetails();

        //Password verfication and Menu 

        class Book
        {
            public string bookId;
            public int tempbookId;
            public string bookAuthor;
            public string bookName;
            public int bookCount;
            public int x;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader("bokfil.txt");
            string s;
            while((s = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Book book = new Book();
                Book newBook = new Book();
                string[] bookData = s.Split(',');
                book.bookName = bookData[0];
                book.bookAuthor = bookData[1];
                book.bookId = bookData[2];
                book.tempbookId = int.Parse(book.bookId);
                newBook.Add(new Book(book.bookName, book.bookAuthor, book.tempbookId));
            }
            readFile.Close();
```

This is supposed to be the start of a library management system but I don't quite understand why it won't let me do this, according to VS the error lies in `newBook.Add(new Book(book.bookName, book.bookAuthor, book.tempbookId));` that line. On .add it says "Program.Book does not contain a definition for "add"....." and on "new Book" it says "Program.Book does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: well, your `Book`-class has no method called `Add`. Pretty obvious. Seems like you need a `newBook-Add(...)`?

Comment: Comment out `Book newBook = new Book();`. and `static Book book = new Book();`.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend storing data in the text file as JSON.

Comment: _Why_ do you have `Book newBook = new Book();` inside your loop? This hides the field to which you want to add.

Comment: `newBook.Add(new Book(book.bookName, book.bookAuthor, book.tempbookId));` should be `newBook.Add(book);`

Comment: you should also name your list `books`, not `newBook`. You´re confusing yourself with your names. Give **different** things **different** names. And make collections of things like books plural, so you have a list of book**s** named `books` (nortice the trailing `s`).